# ¿Cómo hago para que las imágenes de un slider de Bootstrap 4 tenga opacidad?

Tags: html, bootstrap, css3

sucede que quiero colocar opacidad a unas imágenes de un slider y no he podido, aquí les muestro como lo tengo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero que quede algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según tengo entendido se utliza el Pseudo-elemento ::before, pero no me funciona, la imagen donde está la opacidad si me resulta ya que utilizo unas clases propias de Bootstrap para los div, pero, como este es un slider no funciona igual, ayudaa!!! Gracias

Este es el código *html* que utilizo:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="assets/img/demo/7.jpg" class="d-block w-100 overlay overlay-blue" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h5>COMUNIDAD DE PAZ </h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="assets/img/demo/9.jpg" class="d-block w-100 overlay overlay-blue" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h5>IMPUNIDAD</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="assets/img/demo/5.jpg" class="d-block w-100 overlay overlay-blue" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h5>NUESTRO TRABAJO</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Y el CSS:

```
  .carousel-item {
 height: 100vh;
 min-height: 300px;
 background: no-repeat center center scroll;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}

.carousel-caption {
 bottom: 243px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
 .carousel-caption h5 {
     font-size: 28px!important;
 }
}
.carousel-caption h5 {
 font-size: 3.5rem;
 font-weight: 300;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Podrías usar la propiedad [filter](https://blog.endeos.com/8-filtros-css-para-imagenes-que-todo-disenador-web-deberia-conocer/)

Comment: Charls utilicé uno de los ejemplos que me suministrastes y me sirvieron de mucho, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

hice un ejemplo de como podrías aplicarlo con `::before`:

Explicación:

Hace referencia al elemento div con la clase `.carousel-inner` y a cada uno de sus hijos con el elemento div y que tengan la clase `.carousel-item` le aplica el pseudo-elemento `::before` dentro de cada uno.

```
div.carousel-inner div.carousel-item::before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #2121218c;
    content: "";
}
```

Comment: Esta comunidad es excelente,utilice este ejemplo y también me sirvió para lo que necesitaba, ¡Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Cambia la opacidad desde el elemento así:

```
img {
  opacity: 0.5; // Cuanto menor sea el valor mas transparente es la imagen. 
}
```

Aquí te amplían más la explicación https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp